# GitLab CI allow job run only when commit message differs from regex

Tags: shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using GitLab.com. I want to run a job when it's on the beta branch and the commit message doesn't start with: `chore(release)`. Here is my attempt:

```yaml
# --snip--

release_beta:
  stage:  release
  image: 
    name: <private_image>
    entrypoint:
      - '/usr/bin/env'
      - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
  before_script:
    - cp $SR_CONFIG_PATH/.releaserc.json .
  script:
    - npx semantic-release
  rules:
    # so we don't trigger a release job when semantic-release pushes the release
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "beta" && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE !~ /^chore(release)/'
```

This doesn't work and the job is always triggered on the `beta` branch. I tried with `=~` variation and it didn't work either. I can't seem to make the regex test work even though it's mentioned in the documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules.

[image: screenshot from documentation]

The job failed because the user doesn't have the permissions for that image (that's the reason I want to prevent the job from running in the first place):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses define capturing groups. You have to escape them to match literal parentheses.

```
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "beta" && $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE !~ /^chore\(release\)/'
```